# Transform scala to Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to transform the code below into spark, But I dont understand what exactly Sql perform in this code ?

```
val tempFactDF = unionTempDF.join(fact.select("x","y","d","f","s"),
                                  Seq("x","y","d","f")).dropDuplicates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is performing a join operation over multiple columns and it is defined as `Seq("x","y","d","f")`.

It is equivalent to:

```
val joiningTable = fact.select("x","y","d","f","s")
unionTempDF.join(joiningTable, unionTempDF("x") === joiningTable("x") &&
unionTempDF("y") === joiningTable("y") &&
unionTempDF("d") === joiningTable("d") &&
unionTempDF("f") === joiningTable("f"))
```

Comment: is this correct for transformation to Pyspark? 
tempFactDF = unionTempDF.join(f"x","y","d","f"]).distinct()

Comment: Yes to be precise `unionTempDF.join(joiningTable, ['x', 'y', 'd', 'f']).distinct()`